# AttributeError when checking if a key exist in a dictionary, using python

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am using Python 2.7.2+, and when trying to see if a dictionary holds a given string value (named func) I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Translator.py", line 125, in <module>
    elif type == Parser.C_ARITHMETIC : parseFunc()
  File "Translator.py", line 95, in parseFunc
    if unary.has_key(func) : 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

This is where I define the dictionaries:

```
binary = {"add":'+', "sub":'-', "and":'&', "or":'|'}
relational = {"eq":"JEQ" , "lt":"JLT", "gt":"JGT"}
unary = {"neg":'-'}
```

Here's the function where the exception is raised:

```
def parseFunc():
    func = parser.arg1 
    print func  
    output.write("//pop to var1" + endLine)
    pop(var1)
    if unary.has_key(func) : // LINE 95
        unary()
        return
    output.write("//pop to var2" + endLine)
    pop(var2)
    result = "//"+func + endLine
    result += "@" + var1 + endLine
    result += "D=M" + endLine
    result += "@" + var2 + endLine
    output.write(result)
    if binary.has_key(func) : 
        binary()
    else : relational()
```

Also, I tried changing `if unary.has_key(func)` to `if func in unary` but then I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Translator.py", line 126, in <module>
    elif type == Parser.C_ARITHMETIC : parseFunc()
  File "Translator.py", line 95, in parseFunc
    if func in unary:
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable
```

P.s I tired it also using python 3.2

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.has_key()` is gone (and it has been deprecated for quite some time).  Use `x in my_dict` instead.

Your problem is a different one, though.  While your definition shows `unary` should be a dictionary, the traceback shows it actually is a function.  So somewhere in the code you did not show, `unary` is redefined.

And even if `unary` was a dictionary, you would not be able to call it.

Comment: even if python 2.7.2+ is ambiguous - I don't think the issue lies in your first part of the answer, though it's correct.

Comment: @luke14free: Did you read the penultimate line of the original post?

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your trace that you override the value of unary with a function (do you have any function called "unary"?). Therefore you are trying to call "has_key" method on a function that obviously has no such method. Pay attention with variable names, variable x will override def x() if it's placed after it in your code, and vice versa.